# A* algorithm not reaching end point with danger nodes

Tags: java, processing, a-star

I am trying to implement A* algorithm visually in Processing. It works fine if I run it simply.

[image]

But when I try to implement danger areas, the algorithm fails to work. I created the danger areas by setting an instance variable danger to true for some of the nodes.

[image]
Here is the A* algorithm code

```
ArrayList astar(Node start, Node end)
{
  Set<Node> closedset = new HashSet<Node>();

  Set<Node> openset = new HashSet<Node>();
  openset.add(start);
  Map<Node, Node> camefrom = new HashMap<Node, Node>();
  Map<Node, Integer> gscore = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
  Map<Node, Integer> fscore = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
  for(Node node: nodes)
  {
    println(end.center);
    gscore.put(node,10000);

    fscore.put(node,10000);
  }
  gscore.put(start,0);

  fscore.put(start,(int)start.disttogoal);

  while(!openset.isEmpty())
  {
    Node current = end;
    Iterator it = fscore.entrySet().iterator();
    int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if((int)pair.getValue()<=dist)
        {
          dist = (int)pair.getValue();
          current = (Node)pair.getKey();
        }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }

    if(current == end) return repath(camefrom, current);

    openset.remove(current);
    closedset.add(current);
    for(Node neigh: current.neighbours)
    {
      if(closedset.contains(neigh)) continue;
      if(neigh.danger) continue;
      int tentg = gscore.get(current) + (int)dist(current.center.x,current.center.y, neigh.center.x,neigh.center.y);
      if(!openset.contains(neigh)) openset.add(neigh);
      else if(tentg >= gscore.get(neigh)) continue;

      camefrom.put(neigh, current);
      gscore.put(neigh, tentg);
      fscore.put(neigh, (int)(gscore.get(neigh)+neigh.disttogoal));
    }
  }
  return null;


}
ArrayList repath(Map camefrom, Node current)
{
  ArrayList<Node> totalpath = new ArrayList<Node>();
  totalpath.add(current);
  for(Object curr: camefrom.keySet())
  {
      totalpath.add((Node)camefrom.get(curr));
  }
  /*while(camefrom.get(current) != null)
  {
    totalpath.add((Node)camefrom.get(current));
    current = (Node)camefrom.get(current);
  }
  */
  return totalpath;
}
```

and here is the node initialization code:

```
for(int i = 100; i <= 300; i+=20)
  {
    for(int j = 100; j <= 300; j+=20)
    {
      Node node = new Node(i,j);
      node.disttogoal = dist(300,300,i,j);
      nodes.add(node);
      if((i>260 && i<=280)||(i>100 && i<=180))
      if((j>100 && j<=300)||(j>100 && j<=0))
        {node.danger = true;
        node.disttogoal = 100000;  
      }
    }
  }

  elems.push(nodes.get(0));
  drawLines(11);
  //dfs(nodes.get(0));
  finpath = astar(nodes.get(0), nodes.get(120));
  for(Node nod : finpath)
  {
    if(nod.danger) nod.dangerlyvisited = true;
    else nod.visited = true;
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your `repath`. Isn't it just adding *all visited nodes* to the path? The commented-out code makes more sense

Comment: Actually the commented out code wasn't showing anything at all.. so I thought of showing all the visited nodes..

Comment: So the data in camefrom is wrong then, does it give any hints as to why it might be wrong?

Comment: I have no definitive answer, but maybe your dist(...) method does create large integer values, which could make the chosen path actually ideal. This is tough to answer as you have hidden how you calculate the weight of your egdes between nodes.

Comment: Dist function is just straight line distance between centers of the goal node and current node

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected? Can you please narrow your problem down to a [mcve]?